# Powershell find and store the file name

Tags: powershell

How do I search for a file and store the file name in a variable.
I can find the file info by doing

```
Get-Item myf* | Select-Object Name
```

I get

```
Name
----
myfile101.csv
```

How do I get just the file name without the "Name" heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options for your specific use case

```
Get-Item myf* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
(Get-Item myf* | Select-Object Name).Name
```

A bit of backgroud

The `Select-Object Name` still returns an object, not just a string.
You can verify yourself by adding `| Get-Member`

```
   TypeName: Selected.System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
Name        NoteProperty string Name=myfile
```